How to remove object from collection only?
Using bpy, how do I remove an object from a collection without also removing it from other places?
I have an object that is both part of a collection and at the same time a child of another object. I try to unlink it from the collection:
collection.objects.unlink(obj)

But it also disappears from the other object.
Even in the GUI I can't seem to remove it from only one place in the outliner. How do I do this right?
EDIT:
The reason why I got here:
I have this structure:
 - Collection1
 -   Collection2
 -     Object1
 -       ObjectToBeMoved
 -   Object3

I want to move Object2 from Object1 to Object3. So I do:
ObjectToBeMoved.parent = Object3

I end up with this:
 - Collection1
 -   Collection2
 -     ObjectToBeMoved
 -     Object1
 -   Object3
 -     ObjectToBeMoved

It gets the new parent (Object3) but it also moves up in the hierarchy to become sibling with its former parent, under Collection2. That's why I want to delete it from Collection2. But when I do that it also disappears from Object3.
Is there another, better, way to move an object?

have you explicitly linked ObjectToBeMoved to Collection1 somewhere? I can't see that step in your description. Keep in mind that parenting does not move the object to the other collection, it only sets the parent.

No, they are not explicitly linked. But I suppose that when I change the parent for ObjectToBeMoved, it is no longer a child of Object1, so it somehow "floats up" to the nearest collection.  So if I also make it belong to Collection1 it would disappear from Collection2(?). Can be worth to try at least.

When you unlink an object that is only linked to 1 collection it will become "orphaned", it will still exist in your data but will not be referenced by anything.
You need to link it against at least 1 collection to make it accessible in your Scene.
bpy.data.collections['Defaults'].objects.unlink(bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'])
will remove the object from the collection and make it an orphan which you can see in the "Unused Data" tab.

bpy.data.collections['New_Coll'].objects.link(bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'])
will once again link it to another collection.
I wrote a small operator to help me move objects between collections for this exact reason. It's part of a much bigger addon but you can link it to a button in the "n" menu easily.
from bpy.types import Operator


class CAD_VIEW_OT_move_to_coll(Operator):
    bl_idname = "cad_view.move_to_coll"
    bl_label = "Move Objects to Collection"
    bl_description = "Moves the selected objects to the active objects collection"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == "VIEW_3D" and len(context.selected_objects) > 0

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        active_object = context.active_object
        coll_target = active_object.users_collection[0]
        selected_objects = [obj for obj in context.selected_objects]

        for obj in selected_objects:
            if obj is not active_object:
                for coll in obj.users_collection:
                    coll.objects.unlink(obj)
                coll_target.objects.link(obj)

        return {"FINISHED"}

